# Vim: how to set filetype for none extension file by `#!`?

Tags: vim

How could I set file with `#!/usr/bin/env node` filetype to javascript?

Answer (score 68):

Make use of modeline.

Put the following line:

```
// vim: set ft=javascript:
```

[more info about vim's modeline.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic)

Comment: you need to enable the modeline in your .vimrc file.


    set modeline

Comment: you may also need to do something line set modelines=5 in your .vimrc; that tells it to look for the modeline in the first or last 5 lines.  some have it set to 0, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax.  I just used  the SQL coloring `// vim: set ft=sql:` in a cql file.  Note the trailing **`:`**

Comment: @taxilian thanks. I could never figure out why half of the time my modelines weren't working. set modelines=5 fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

In vim, `:e $VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim`. This is the file that does filetype detection of "scripts" when there isn't something in the filename (like an extension) that tells vim the type. If you search for "#!" in this file you'll see the logic that does this. The problem is, it's a bunch of special cases and there isn't a fine-grained hook for what you want to do. One possibility would be to modify this scripts.vim file and also submit your modification back to be included in Vim.

If you don't want to modify files that came with vim then an alternative is to create your own `scripts.vim` in your personal runtimepath (use `:set rtp?` to see what it's set to on your system). This will be run *in addition to* the one in $VIMRUNTIME. You can include your logic for looking at the first line and detecting "node". You'll probably want to model your code after the logic in `$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim`.

Comment: I located the file, but can I do this in ~/.vimrc or ~/.vim/*

Comment: You should be able to do this `~/.vim/scripts.vim`. Look at `:h new-filetype-scripts` for an example.

Comment: @guilin 桂林: See the second paragraph of my answer. `~/.vim` is in your runtimepath (by default on Unix), so you can write a `~/.vim/scripts.vim` like Peter Rincker mentions.

Comment: I edited in a code example (as a vim plugin) but you are correct, this will work in ~/.vim/scripts.vim as stated in the help.  The help example is a lot simpler as well.  Feel free to reject/modify the edit.  I just felt that an actual solution would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

[`autocommand`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) can be used to check file types (this is how `$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim` is loaded).

> You can specify commands to be executed automatically when reading or writing
>   a file, when entering or leaving a buffer or window, and when exiting Vim.

...

> WARNING: Using autocommands is very powerful, and may lead to unexpected side
>   effects.  Be careful not to destroy your text.

Add this to your `.vimrc` - it will be invoked when a new file is opened:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if match(getline(1),"node") >= 0 | set filetype=javascript | endif
```